# How to redirect with POST variables with Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I have written the following code:

```java
@Controller
    @RequestMapping("something")
    public class somethingController {
       @RequestMapping(value="/someUrl",method=RequestMethod.POST)
       public String myFunc(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response,Map model){
        //do sume stuffs
         return "redirect:/anotherUrl"; //gets redirected to the url '/anotherUrl'
       }

      @RequestMapping(value="/anotherUrl",method=RequestMethod.POST)
      public String myAnotherFunc(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
        //do sume stuffs
         return "someView"; 
      }
    }
```

How would i be able to redirect to "anotherUrl" request mapping whose request method is POST?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A spring Controller methods can be both POST and GET requests.

In your scenario:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/anotherUrl",method=RequestMethod.POST)
  public String myAnotherFunc(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
    //do sume stuffs
     return "someView"; 
  }
```

You want this GET because you are redirecting to it.
Hence your solution will be

```
  @RequestMapping(value="/anotherUrl", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
      public String myAnotherFunc(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response){
        //do sume stuffs
         return "someView"; 
      }
```

Caution : here, if your method accepts some request parameters by @requestParam,then while redirecting you must pass them.

Simply all attributes required by this method must send while redirecting...

Thank You.

Comment: bindingResults are being lost this way sir. Any solution.?

Comment: No binding results will be lost. Here we are only telling handle method to accept both GET and POST method.

Comment: While from a technical standpoint this will work, if you are writing a RESTful application this would violate the "no-side-effects" expectation for GET - so anyone pursuing this solution, be aware of that break in convention. I'd advise either finding another way or documenting it really, really well (at very minimum)

Comment: how we will send post request with parameter? we are returning only string.

Comment: this isn't even an answer to the question, why has it been voted as accepted answer?