# Spring MVC and redirect on POST sends destination file on URL

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, post

I have a very weird problem in my Spring MVC application. I am writing a login form and POSTing the data via AJAX into a Spring MVC controller that looks like this:

```
@Controller
public class LoginResourceController {
   private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger    (LoginResourceController.class.getName());

   @RequestMapping (value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public String checkAccount (HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse    httpResponse,
            @RequestHeader (value = "User-Agent") String retrievedUserAgent,
            @RequestParam("username") String username, 
            @RequestParam("password") String password,
            @RequestParam("rememberMe") String rememberMe)
   {
       //Check username and password in DB, and then if OK,
        return "redirect:/login/redirectToMain";
   }

@RequestMapping (value = "/login/redirectToMainpage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String redirectControllerToMainPage (HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse httpResponse)
{
return "mainPage";
}
```

Now, the problem is, I have the client (browser) upon redirect requesting a URL that contains the *entire contents* of `mainPage.jsp` in the URL. So it looks like:

`https://localhost:8443/<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset=utf-8 /><title>Page that the subscriber sees after login</title>....`

I am quite confounded by this error. Is this some servlet setting in `WEB-INF/web.xml` or `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` that I need to change? I am using Spring 3.0.5.

BTW, my redirect works flawlessly for `GET` method controllers in the same Spring MVC application. (e.g., when I re-load the main page of my application, the redirect to the logged in `mainPage.jsp` above works flawlessly). Moreover, other `GET` methods on other jsps work correctly too (example, redirect to `/login` page via `login.jsp` via a `GET` of `https://localhost:8443/`.

I have checked the following and they didn't help: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526445/how-to-redirect-to-post-in-spring-mvc) [2](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/114038-how-to-redirect-to-a-new-url-in-spring-3-1-mvc).

Comment: Confirmed the same unexplainable behavior using Spring 4.0.3 too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a little tricky for me to figure out, and being a web development noob doesn't help here. Anyway, @jhadesdev's answer above pointed me to the issue.

On my client, I do this:

```
$("#loginForm").submit(function(evt)
{
    evt.preventDefault();

    if (loginFormInputIsValid ())
    {
       $.ajax ({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/login",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (response)
                {
                   window.location = response;
                }
         });
    }
}
```

which was the issue--you see, setting the `window.location=response;` caused the client (browser) to request the server for the funky URL above. I have to change my client call (this is where @jhadesdev's response helped) to make sure I don't do something so wrong.

Thanks for your time, @jhadesdev.

Comment: Got this working. I did not change my AJAX call. Instead, I changed my controller implementation to return a `@ResponseBody` like the article in `http://blog.brunoraljic.com/ajax-with-spring-mvc/` and now return a String URL the client should perform a `GET` on. I do need a mapping in my `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` file for the URL requested by the browser to map to some internal file in the web app, say, into some directory in `WEB-INF/jsp` (see `http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-how-to-include-js-or-css-files-in-a-jsp-page/`). Now, everything works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Try not to put the redirect in the return of the controller. This seems to either cause the full page to be rendered as the ajax response, or a redirect header is filled in with an url with the full contents of the page as a string in the response body.

As a first approach, try to make the request a normal HTTP request instead of ajax, and it should just work.

Alternativelly try to make the return body empty, and return an HTTP status code to the client. Either `200 OK`if the account is OK or `401 Unauthorized`:

```
  @RequestMapping (value="/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
   public ResponseEntity checkAccount (HttpServletRequest httpRequest, HttpServletResponse    httpResponse,
            @RequestHeader (value = "User-Agent") String retrievedUserAgent,
            @RequestParam("username") String username, 
            @RequestParam("password") String password,
            @RequestParam("rememberMe") String rememberMe)
   {
       //Check username and password in DB
       ....
       HttpStatus returnCode = null;

       if(usernameAndPasswordOK) {
           returnCode = HttpStatus.OK;
       }   
       else {
           returnCode = HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED;
       }    

        return new ResponseEntity(returnCode);
   }
```

And then on the client redirect with Javascript accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @jhadesdev. It turns out that my jquery call was incorrect. I will upvote your answer because your response pointed me to the error which I show in my answer, but the issue was that I do a `window.location` on the Ajax response, which is clearly the issue.