# How to specify POST method while returning modelview in controller?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Here is the code:

```
return new ModelAndView("redirect:/admin/create");
```

And here is what I get while running application:
**http://localhost:4647/GenAppRegistration/admin/create?accessmethod=direct**

I want to make it load like this:
**http://localhost:4647/GenAppRegistration/admin/create**

So how can I get specify in **return statement** that POST method has to occur while returning the view?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18526445/how-to-redirect-to-post-in-spring-mvc Similar question. Check this out.

Comment: The question is similar. But this doesnt answer my question. User asked about how to redirect url to POST method and the answer got is about GET method. I dont know why people marked it as best answer, may be they didnt understand what the guy actually asked for. I repeat, I dont want my url to be like url/url1?param=abc after redirection, instead I need url/url1 only..

Answer (score 0):

Remove `accessmethod` from model Before return :

1. if u use `ModelAndView` mav :

   `mav.getModelMap().remove("accessmethod");`
2. if u use `Model` md :

   `md.remove("accessmethod");`